# CreditMemo revert has blank response / doesn't revert

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, devkit

For some reason when I try to revert a credit memo in Quickbooks IPP, I get a blank response. I removed the authorization header so I could post it below The request:

```
POST https://services.intuit.com/sb/creditmemo/v2/[realmid] HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 312

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<Revert RequestId="73c6e0d1268aaac3a34e8e00a73d0e74"
   xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
   <Object xsi:type="CreditMemo"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Id idDomain="NG">46537073</Id>
   </Object>
</Revert>
```

The response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 22 Aug 2013 06:39:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
Response-Routing-Time: 185
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

I'm using the php devkit

Comment: you can't revert credit memo if there is a linked transaction like against it

Comment: so then how can I get it out of an error state?

Comment: An object can be reverted only if it has been synched with QuickBooks at least once. This implies that the object has been updated by  Data Services (that is, by a <Mod> operation) and yes, there should not any linked transaction against it

Comment: Thanks. How can I get it out of error state if it has already been synced once, but does have transactions against it?

Comment: Can you try doing an update directly? It is not documented in our docs but works sometimes.

Comment: Well, for credit memo, I don't see any TXNId field, so revert also should work. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/creditmemo

Comment: I can try that. Is there a way to get it included in a creditmemo query?

Comment: I need to be able to get the current xml of the object so I can update it without missing anything.

Comment: I found out credit memos don't support revert: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0500_supported_objects

Comment: Is there a way for me to query for the credit memo even though it's in error state?

Comment: I figured it out. added ErroredObjectsOnly="true" to my query.

Comment: @Jeremy you should post an answer with your finding so it's documented for others in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you can't revert a credit memo according to the Intuit developer site: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0500_supported_objects

What I ended up doing to resolve the issue was doing a query with ErroredObjectsOnly="true" to get the currently errored credit memo:

```
<CreditMemoQuery ErroredObjectsOnly="true" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
</CreditMemoQuery>
```

and then posting my credit memo back to intuit with valid fields. That bumped the CreditMemo out of error state and allowed it to sync.